# How would a Nuclear Salt Water Rocket (NSWR) compare to rocket fuel?

Tags: hard-science

Assuming that a [Nuclear Salt Water Rocket (NSWR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_salt-water_rocket) is possible.

What would be its power to weight ratio, or thrust per KG of fuel? Would it be better or worse than a conventionally-fueled rocket?

Comment: Let's just say it's the most over-the-top rocket design ever conceived that is actually somewhat possible barring concepts like orion and medusa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Nuclear Salt Water Rocket (NSWR)](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/enginelist.php#id--Nuclear_Thermal--Gas_Core--Open_Cycle--Nuclear_Salt_Water)

NSWR:
[image: NSWR]

20% UTB

```
Exhaust Velocity        66,000 m/s
Specific Impulse         6,728 s     
Thrust              12,900,000 N
Thrust Power               425.7 GW              
Mass Flow              195 kg/s
Total Engine Mass       33,000 kg
```

90% UTB

```
Exhaust Velocity     4,700,000 m/s  
Specific Impulse       479,103 s  
Thrust              13,000,000 N  
Thrust Power                30.6 TW  
Mass Flow                    3 kg/s
```

Far more information available at the link provided above.

Chemical rocket $I_{sp}$ runs between 300 - 550 seconds.  So the 20% enriched NSWR is about 20x more fuel efficient and the 90% enriched is about 1000x more fuel efficient than chemical rockets.